# Generate report from Microsoft Application Insights data

Tags: reporting, azure-application-insights

Currently we use Microsoft Application Insights for performance tracking and it worked very well and we could easily grab the report/chart on Azure portal, the problem is that the application we are monitoring is for one of our clients and we don't want to share the Azure portal with them.

I know there is an AI API which could be used to grab data and do whatever we want, but is there any easy way to share AI data with client without letting them log into the AI portal in AZure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Read-only Power BI dashboard may be the good option here. The steps for couple ways of achieving this integration are [here](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Power-BI). However, you may go even simpler route:

- use an Export button in Analytics UI of Application Insights resource and choose "Power BI (M query)" as a target;
- paste this query as a new data source in Power BI (of type "Blank Query");
- authenticate to AI backend (that's the important part of making this Dashboard read-only, so no one can change the query to extract another data under the same account);
- create visualization;

Another way entirely is to fork subset of the data into customer's AI Resource (AI SDK supports sending data over into several IKeys if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the API Key feature of application insights, and generate a read-only api key, and use the [application insights REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) features to build a custom solution to do the queries and generate reports.  this would let anyone with that API key see *any* telemetry in your app though.